# Named values for a Kotlin Enum item

Tags: android, kotlin, enums

I have a test class that will have difficulty, which values are configured in an AppSettings.kt class

"Difficulty" has five possible values as follows:

```
VeryEasy
Easy
Medium
Difficult
VeryDifficult
```

And each difficulty level has 4 properties, as follows:

```
NumberOfQuestions
NumberOfAnswers
FromXWords
ToYWords
```

I started creating an Enum as this next:

```
enum class Difficulty(val value: Array<Int>) {
    VeryEasy(arrayOf(5, 3, 60, 100)),
    Easy(arrayOf(8, 4, 100, 140)),
    Medium(arrayOf(12, 4, 140, 180)),
    Diffiicult(arrayOf(15, 4, 180, 220)),
    VeryDiffiicult(arrayOf(20, 5, 250, 300));
}
```

And it's OK, I can access any member and property as (for example):

```
val numberOfQuestions = Difficulty.Easy[0]
```

But I'd like to access properties with a name like so:

```
val numberOfQuestions = Difficulty.Easy.NumerOfQuestions
```

I know this is quite easy to achieve -for example- with two classes, but I'm sure there must be a simpler approach using enums.

Keep in mind I'll use this as configuration app settings and will be inside an AppSettings class, so the simpler it is, the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define multiple `val`-s in your enum:

```
enum class Difficulty(
    val numberOfQuestions: Int,
    val numberOfAnswers: Int,
    val fromXWords: Int,
    val toYWords: Int,
) {
    VeryEasy(5, 3, 60, 100),
    Easy(8, 4, 100, 140),
    Medium(12, 4, 140, 180),
    Diffiicult(15, 4, 180, 220),
    VeryDiffiicult(20, 5, 250, 300);
}
```

and then retrieve them by name:

```
val numberOfQuestions = Difficulty.Easy.numberOfQuestions
```

Comment: Thank you very much @gdomo. As I said, both answers are similar, and I have to choose one, but thanks for your time, it works just as I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the `value` property as a list, you can define extra properties in enum class.

```kotlin
enum class Difficulty(val value: Array<Int>) {
    VeryEasy(arrayOf(5, 3, 60, 100)),
    Easy(arrayOf(8, 4, 100, 140)),
    Medium(arrayOf(12, 4, 140, 180)),
    Diffiicult(arrayOf(15, 4, 180, 220)),
    VeryDiffiicult(arrayOf(20, 5, 250, 300));

    val numberOfQuestions: Int get() = value[0]
    val numberOfAnswers: Int get() = value[1]
    val fromXWords: Int get() = value[2]
    val toYWords: Int get() = value[3]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ObscureCookie. Both answers are similar, and I have to choose one, but I appreciate your time, so thanks again, it works just as I was expecting.